# php://input is empty on POST request

Tags: php, http, post, multipartform-data

Problems with `multipart/form-data` forced me to parse POST request's parameters manually as I already doing for PUT requests. For that purpose I used this code:

```
$rawData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

But I figured that `php://input` is always empty for POSTs, at least, for `php-fpm` SAPI.

Here is some pics from debugger. POST request:

[image: empty $rawData]

PUT with same params:

[image: filled $rawData]

Is there a way to get raw POST request body? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the meanwhile a pointer to PHP man page why raw data is not available for POST http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: RE: the comment above, it IS AVAILABLE for POST request, but it IS NOT AVAILABLE with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` forms ;)

Comment: Correct, that's what we're talking about (see the question).

Comment: I suggest you give a look to a couple of answers here on SO: (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707632/php-http-request-content-raw-data-enctype-multipart-form-data (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561078/userland-multipart-form-data-handler

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli Sure, i didn't say you were wrong, just hiding the key issue for this question ^^

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli so, the answer is there in no way. Why do not you write an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Before PHP 5.4** `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not available with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (with the exception of some SAPI implementations), explanations here:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

I suggest you give a look to a couple of answers to existing questions:

- [php http request content raw data enctype=multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707632/php-http-request-content-raw-data-enctype-multipart-form-data)
- [userland multipart/form-data handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561078/userland-multipart-form-data-handler)

**From PHP 5.4+** you can use the `php.ini` directive [`enable_post_data_reading`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading) to disable PHP consuming the raw data (hence process it), be aware that `$_POST` and `$_FILES` won't be populated though (refer to [Vitaly Chirkov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192068/565110)).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

```
var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Source:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php
```

===
Edit - this will not show the raw post data for 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: That wouldn't work `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Comment: Looks like: **php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"** also [php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)